# project.json dependencies targeting different versions of NETStandard.Library

Tags: .net, .net-core, standard-library

I have a class library where `project.json` file looks as follows:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "System.Security.Claims": "4.0.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.2": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

It targets `netstandard1.2` and at the same time uses `System.Security.Claims.4.0.1` which depends on `netstandard1.3`. And also it uses `NETStandard.Library.1.6.0`. This means that I can use any classes/methods which don't exist in `netstandard1.2`. But at the same time my project compiles well regardless of it.

Why doesn't it throw error? It looks like the compiler doesn't validate platforms listed in `"frameworks"` section against global dependencies, right? But what is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line  `"imports": "dnxcore50"` is the reason why it works. If you delete it, you will have a `Package System.Security.Claims 4.0.1 is not compatible with netstandard1.2 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.2).`.

And for `"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",`, only dependencies with `netstandard1.2` and less will be referenced, so you won't be able to use any classes/methods which don't exist in `netstandard1.2` (the 1.6.0 does not link to `netstandard1.6`)

Comment: Then what is difference between `"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"` and `netstandard1.6` in this case?

Comment: The `"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"` is a metapackage that contains all dependencies for building application/library that targets `netstandard` until 1.6, but you will be limited by the framework you used. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/packages)